# Stop Debugger to Debug IL

Tags: debugging

My debugger keep jumping into debugging the IL instead of jumping to debug code of another assembly. How can I turn it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio right?

**Tools** -> **Options**

Click the **Debugging** section then deselect the **Show disassembly if source is not available** checkbox

But that will leave you without any debug information if source is not available. It sounds like the debug information is missing from those assemblies. Maybe they were built in release mode? Or the pdb files have not been copied? Of course if you don't have access to the original source code then it won't make any difference

Comment: You are right for some reason those assemblies were missing! Not sure what happened as I was using them last week and never deleted them. Thanks!